# Get json data into Highcharts scatter plot

Tags: php, json, highcharts, scatter

I cannot get Highcharts to graph a scatter plot of 2 series. Actually, the graph isn't even showing up. Please help me determine what I'm doing wrong. I cannot find a scatter plot example to go off of and I am very new to this. I've got json data from a php file that looks like:

```
[[65,44],[66,37],[67,42],[68,55],[65,50],[65,41],[65,41],[68,41],[69,42],[70,47],[69,55],[67,45],[67,49],[67,53],[67,49],[68,51],[68,55],[68,57],[70,53],[69,66],[68,54],[69,52],[68,48]][[75,36],[72,42],[75,44],[69,56],[72,40],[73,37],[77,34],[77,40],[74,50],[77,45],[77,43],[75,47],[73,52],[73,50],[75,44],[72,54],[71,57],[72,57],[74,55],[74,54],[75,47],[78,45],[75,43]]
```

This should be two series in an (x,y) format. I want to graph these on a scatter plot in HighCharts. My HighCharts code is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("comfortgb1b.php", function(json) {

               chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container4',
                    type: 'scatter',
                    marginRight: 175,
                    marginBottom: 50
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Comfort Level',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        enabled: true,
                        text: 'Temp (F)'
                    },
                    min: 60,
                    max: 85,
                    startOnTick: true,
                    endOnTick: true,
                    showLastLabel: true
                },
                yAxis:  {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Humidity (%RH)'
                    },                  
                    min: 30,
                    max: 100
                },                
                plotOptions: {
                scatter: {
                    marker: {
                        radius: 5,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true,
                                lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            }
                        }
                    },
                     tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                        pointFormat: '{point.x} F, {point.y} %RH'
                    }
                },
                 series: [{
                    name: 'Night',
                    data: json(1)
                               }, {
                                    name: 'Night',
                    data: json(2)
                     });
        });

    });

});
        </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

The php file that is creating the json data is below. How would I separate these arrays with a comma?

```
  $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT round(AVG(d_internal_duct_return),0) AS 'avg_return', round(AVG(d_evap_pre_humidity),0) AS 'avg_hum' FROM pheom.pheom_gb WHERE timestamp between subdate(curdate(), interval 2 month) and curdate()  AND HOUR(Timestamp) NOT BETWEEN 9 AND 22 GROUP BY DAY(Timestamp) ORDER BY Timestamp");
$ret1 = array();
while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $avg_return1 = $item['avg_return'];
    $avg_hum1 = $item['avg_hum'];
    $ret1[] = array($avg_return1,$avg_hum1);
}

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT round(AVG(d_internal_duct_return),0) AS 'avg_return', round(AVG(d_evap_pre_humidity),0) AS 'avg_hum' FROM pheom.pheom_gb WHERE timestamp between subdate(curdate(), interval 2 month) and curdate()  AND HOUR(Timestamp) BETWEEN 9 AND 22 GROUP BY DAY(Timestamp) ORDER BY Timestamp");
$ret2 = array();
while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $avg_return2 = $item['avg_return'];
    $avg_hum2 = $item['avg_hum'];
    $ret2[] = array($avg_return2,$avg_hum2);
}
echo json_encode($ret1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo json_encode($ret2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: that PHP script will only give you 1 series. Are you sure it gives the same output as you mentioned in the beginning? Are you running the script twice?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I pasted the wrong one. See the corrected version above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about this, but at first glance I think the array returned from the php file requires an additional square bracket outside it in order to be parsed as proper json. Currently it is:

```
[[65,44],[66,37]..][[75,36],[72,42]..]
```

From what I know, this is just two arrays. What you want is to enclose these arrays within an array. Try changing this to:

```
[[[65,44],[66,37]..],[[75,36],[72,42]..]]
```

That is, add an extra square bracket outside and separate the two arrays using a comma.

In addition, here:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Night',
        data: json(1)
    }, {
        name: 'Night',
        data: json(2)
});
```

json(1) and json(2) are interpreted as function calls. You should instead use:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Night',
        data: json[0]
    }, {
        name: 'Night',
        data: json[1]
});
```

EDIT ---- Edited as per OP edits

Also as requested, in order to add the commas and proper formatting, the php file can be changed at the last two lines as follows:

```
echo "[".json_encode($ret1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK).",";
echo json_encode($ret2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)."]";
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! Now, one last problem. how do I edit my Highcharts file to pull that data? I used Jack's fiddle and it works. But when I try to pull json data from the php file, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have several things giving you problems. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nbwN9/1/

First, I don't think your json is in the proper format for a 2 series plot. You have two arrays of data just butted up to each other rather than in another array. The linked fiddle corrects that (and stuffs it into a var since the getJSON() call will fail within jsFiddle). Each point is an array of (x,y) coords. Each series.data is an array of points. Your json will need to be an array of series.data arrays. So we're looking at nested arrays 3 deep.

Second, you seem to have a malformed set of chart options. Most notable is that your series node (with name and data) is inside your plotOptions node when it should be outside of it. And that series node is not terminated properly.

Third, once you get your json data and your chart options formatted correctly, accessing the json array is done like so:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Night',
        data: json[0]
    }, {
        name: 'Day',
        data: json[1]
    }]
```

The array is 0-based (so the first record will be indexed with a 0, second record with a 1, etc) and is access using the brackets **[]** not parentheses **()**

Sorry, I renamed one of your series to "Day" so I could see the difference in the chart.

As far as the PHP script... try this:

```
  $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT round(AVG(d_internal_duct_return),0) AS 'avg_return', round(AVG(d_evap_pre_humidity),0) AS 'avg_hum' FROM pheom.pheom_gb WHERE timestamp between subdate(curdate(), interval 2 month) and curdate()  AND HOUR(Timestamp) NOT BETWEEN 9 AND 22 GROUP BY DAY(Timestamp) ORDER BY Timestamp");

  $ret1 = array();
  while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
      $avg_return1 = $item['avg_return'];
      $avg_hum1 = $item['avg_hum'];
      $ret1[] = array($avg_return1,$avg_hum1);
  }

  $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT round(AVG(d_internal_duct_return),0) AS 'avg_return', round(AVG(d_evap_pre_humidity),0) AS 'avg_hum' FROM pheom.pheom_gb WHERE timestamp between subdate(curdate(), interval 2 month) and curdate()  AND HOUR(Timestamp) BETWEEN 9 AND 22 GROUP BY DAY(Timestamp) ORDER BY Timestamp");

  $ret2 = array();
  while($item = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
      $avg_return2 = $item['avg_return'];
      $avg_hum2 = $item['avg_hum'];
      $ret2[] = array($avg_return2,$avg_hum2);
  }

  echo json_encode(array($ret1,$ret2), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Comment: Thank you. I posted my json php code above. Can you help me get a comma between the arrays?